# Search and Replace Strings in a Text File Using Wildcards

Tags: python, regex

Trying to do a search/replace in python using wildcards on the contents of a text file:

If the contents of the text file looks like:

```
"all_bcar_v0038.ma";
"all_bcar_v0002.ma";
"all_bcar_v0011.ma";
"all_bcar_v0011.ma";
```

Looking to replace all the version numbers with v1000 to get this:

```
"all_bcar_v1000.ma";
"all_bcar_v1000.ma";
"all_bcar_v1000.ma";
"all_bcar_v1000.ma";
```

And have the file written out.

I've tried the below but what happens is the script only catches the first version number, leaving the others untouched:

```
def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
    if searchExp in line:
    line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
    sys.stdout.write(line)

rigs = ['all_bcar']
rigs_latest = ['all_bcar_v1000']

old_pattern = []
old_compiled = []
old = []
old_version = []

for rig in range(len(rigs)):
    old_pattern.append("/" + rigs[rig] + "_(.*).ma")
    fin = open(txt_file, "r")

    old_compiled.append(re.compile(old_pattern[rig]))
    old.append(old_compiled[rig].search(fin.read()))
    old_version.append(old[rig].group(1).strip())
    old_rig = (rigs[rig] + "_" + old_version[rig])
    replaceAll(txt_file,old_rig,rigs_latest[rig])


fin.close()
```

Not sure how to keep the search looping to find other versions and to avoid the versions that have already been replaced, to skip any versions that equal "v1000".

Answer (score 6):

Your life would be vastly improved with the use of [regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html). You should be able to do this in 2 lines (assuming I understand the problem correctly):

```
import re

for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
  re.sub(r"_v\d{4}", "_v1000", line)
```

Comment: Wow, I was wasting a lot of lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
import re

re.sub("_v\d{4}", "_v1000.", string)
```